# On IIS in Windows 7 ASP.Net pages CSS is not show correclty as In the embedded server in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, css, iis

I am facing a problem with CSS on the IIS installted on Windows 7. It is not displaying correctly as what is shown in the  embedded server in Visual Studio 2010 when previewing the page.

For example, the jquery dialog title is not showing correctly:

In Visual Studio 2010:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/151/cssiis1.jpg/

On IIS 7 On Windows 7:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/197/cssiis2.jpg/

Also I am using transparent css effects and it not working on IIS but is working on Visual Studio.

`filter: alpha(opacity=60);   opacity: 0.60;`

What is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: did u overwrite the styles from JqueryUI??

Comment: no I didn't touch anything and is not only with jquery-ui other css styling have the same problem.

Comment: check once more through fiddler if correct css file is served by IIS.

Comment: I tried fiddler and it get the file from IIS. Also another note that other styling properties are working correctly but other don't one of them the ones above.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this proplem copy all style in CSS file and past it in style tag in master page. I did that and it working.
I take all from CSS file and past it in  past her